# Not able to type in terminal in vs code

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

Have installed angular CLI via node js command prompt. However, when I launch terminal in VS code, it doesn't allow to type only. PFA screenshot

[image]

PFB terminal setting screenshot

[image]

Able to run ng commands from node js command prompt outside vs code.

[image]

Comment: As I can see in the screen shot, There is nothing as the default shell for your terminal. it should be as '1:Powershell', '1:cmd' or bash. But t is blank for you ie '1:' in the bottom panel top right in the terminal section. Go to Veiw>intregated terminal and try customizing it.

Comment: @SandeepPatel Following is Vs code and other softwares versions.

Version: 1.36.0
Commit: 0f3794b38477eea13fb47fbe15a42798e6129338
Date: 2019-07-03T13:25:46.372Z
Electron: 4.2.5
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.15063

In edit, there comes option as "Terminal" and not as "Integrated Terminal". Is there anything that need to set in Settings:

Comment: yes. so when you click on terminal do you see anything, a pop would display for few seconds at the left bottom panel. if so try customizing it. also have a look on this https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuration

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is not related to **default shell** in your terminal. Then you check windows settings. Follow the steps -

- Open **VSCode** file location
- Go to **Compatibility** tab in **VSCode properties** window
- Unchecked **Run this program in compatibility mode for:** option

see the attached files. Try with this solution, it might help you.
[image]
[image]

Comment: This solved it for me.  I checked the box recently due to instructions in the VS Code documentation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Remove **settings file**.
2. Click on **view/terminal**.
3. Select **default shell**.

Comment: Where is the settings file?